# How to prepare images for Haar Cascade? Positive vs Training samples

Tags: opencv, training-data, haar-classifier

I am preparing to classify my own object using openCV Haar Cascade. I understand that negative images are photos without your object. Positive images are with you object included. The part that confuses me is how my positive images need to be setup. I have read numerous explanations. Its still a bit confusing to me. I've read 3 different methods on preparing samples.

1) Positive images are actual(take up full size of image) and converted to .vec file.
2) Images are apart of background and object box dimension are noted in file then converted a .vec file
3) Positive image is distorted and added to negative background.

Here are some links of articles I've read
https://www.academia.edu/9149928/A_complete_guide_to_train_a_cascade_classifier_filter

https://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html

http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html#w0a08ab4

Do I crop my positive images for training or do I keep as is and include the rectangle dimension of the object within the image?

Comment: Hmm i think regardless rather I crop image or not the .vec file will still have information about the Region of Interest.

Comment: Are there pros and cons to cropping image versus having the image somewhere on the background?

Comment: 2 is the right approach in general. If you want to use full images you'd need huge detector size windows or small input images. You can use 3 to get more positive samples (augmentation), but I prefer to use individual REAL samples with varying background. It is important to understand how the training works, it will search for haar features that are available in all (up to minHitRate loss) positive samples and which are not present in negative samples. From that understanding you can think about what kind of samples and negatives make sense in your task.

Comment: ok, I misunderstood. It makes no difference whether u use cropped rois or full image with roi in the annotation file. After generating the vec file, all samples will be cropped and resized to w x h (24x24 default), so it doesnt matter.

Comment: but you might want to add some background to the roi if you want to keep the aspect ratio of the object during createSamples resizing.